# Python regex match returns a list of matches

Tags: python, regex

I would like to return a list that contains the span and values of all matches that exists in a sentence, but I don't know the exact python syntax.

```
import re
sens = 'SCOTT GORRAN 08:09:17 thx 08:19:33 where do you have eur m17->m27? 6s.  imm rolls. KATHERINE DOUGLAS 08:19:47 sec BARRY CLARK 08:20:16 84 SCOTT GORRAN 08:21:25 offer usd 25k/bp pls'
pattern = r'([\+-]?((\d+(\,\d{3})+)(\.\d+)?)|\d+(\.\d+)?|(\.\d+))'
compiled = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
list_of_matches =[]
for match in compiled.match(sens):
    match_tuple = (match.span(), match.value())
    list_of_matches.append(match_tuple)
```

output should be something like this:

```
[((start,end),value) ... ]

[((13,15),08) , ((16,18),09), ((26,28), 08), ((29,31), 19) ....]
```

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want `re.finditer`...

Comment: So, `list_of_matches = [(m.span(), m.group()) for m in re.finditer(pattern, sens)]` is what you're after or something?

Comment: Yes that worked I think. Thanks Jon.

Comment: Note that you don't need the re.IGNORECASE flag since the pattern doesn't contain letters.